# Tidy configuration: parseString expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, configuration, tidy

Following code gives stated error:

```
$t =  new Tidy();
$t->parseString($html, array('conf1' =>true...),'utf8');
```

pecl tidy 1.2
php 5.3

Comment: What is the value of `$html`? It's supposed to be a string, but the error says that it's an array.

Comment: It should be html but I'll try to debug that once more.
Is parameter 1 really the first parameter or could it be 0? I found one similar problem that suggested the PECL extension is too old but in this case it doesn't match with currently installed versions.

Comment: Parameters are numbered from 1 in error messages. Use `var_dump($html)` to see what it is.

Comment: Thanks! And dough...It was in fact an array. Didn't realize that the api returned an array instead of markup.